# Which one is faster x+=x or x*=2

Tags: performance, rust

I recently make a program to make an image of the Mandelbrot set. To do this is I have written a function which returns if a point is a point of Mandelbrot set. And in this function I found 2 ways to do my calculation:

```rust
let temp=a;
a=a*a-b*b+x;
b=2.0*b*temp+y;
```

or

```
let temp=a;
a=a*a-b*b+x;
b*=temp;
b+=b+y;
```

Which one is faster if there is a faster one? (I use rust language if this changes something)?

Comment: Micro-optimization. You have a thousand more pressing things to worry about than the two-clock-cycle difference between these two nearly-equivalent ways of doing math.

Comment: i make image with 10000*10000 resolution and the calculation can be do 1000 time per pixel so that can make the difrence

Comment: According to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/M88K4WhW8), the compiler optimizes both to `n + n`. Of course, details will vary according to datatype and many other factors, but unless you _really_ know what you're doing, you should probably leave such decisions to the compiler at this phase.

Comment: Remember, if you're bumping up against CPU limits, one of the first things you'll want to do is look for [SIMD solutions](https://docs.rs/simd/latest/simd/). These can multiply both numbers at once, or even multiply-add, which is a very common operation. Beyond that, it's time to offload it into a GPU shader where you can get, in many cases, a 1000x increase in performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put both your codes into the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=5f5e9163cc2133eb105d3c72e6d17c00), as a public functions (assuming that your values are all floats, but this shouldn't make any real diference):

```
pub fn mult(mut a: f32, mut b: f32, x: f32, y: f32) -> f32 {
    let temp = a;
    a = a * a - b * b + x;
    b = 2.0 * b * temp + y;
    b
}

pub fn add(mut a: f32, mut b: f32, x: f32, y: f32) -> f32 {
    let temp = a;
    a = a * a - b * b + x;
    b *= temp;
    b += b + y;
    b
}
```

The assembly generated in release mode is almost identical (just reordered):

```
playground::mult:
    addss   xmm1, xmm1
    mulss   xmm0, xmm1
    addss   xmm0, xmm3
    ret

playground::add:
    mulss   xmm0, xmm1
    addss   xmm3, xmm0
    addss   xmm0, xmm3
    ret
```

So, there should be no measurable difference. However, if you're worried, you should benchmark your real case to see whether some of these approaches leads to missing optimizations in the larger picture.